# RecursiveArrayIterator current array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the whole current array and I don't think I have gone the right way about it as I get an Undefined index error sometimes.

```
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($comments_array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    while ($iterator->valid()) {
        if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
            $row = $iterator->getChildren();
            $depth = $iterator->getDepth();
            echo $row['User_ID'] . "<br>";
        }
        $iterator->next();
    }
```

I know you can do `foreach ($iterator->getChildren() as $key => $value)` but that doesn't help me as I want the whole array.

Hope this makes sense?!

Comment: Is there any particular need to iterate over the array recursively (in other words, what is the structure of the comments array)?

Comment: @salathe see http://pastebin.com/9c2F04dw

Comment: thanks, I'll post up an answer shortly (the array keys will relate to those in this question rather than in your paste, to aid others browsing here)

Comment: answer posted, sorry it took so long, work got in the way. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often approach this kind of task with a filtering iterator, rather than having some crazy nested set of `if` blocks.  Oftentimes, tasks like these can be abstracted out to something more generic--useful for more than just this one array/loop--and this is the approach I've taken here.

Because of that, the answer below is not the *easiest*, *quickest* or *smallest* change to your code to get the job done. However, it might come in useful elsewhere for yourself or anyone else wanting to do something similar with *any* kind of recursive iterator.

---

So, the task boils down to *how can I get only the parents of an iterator (or array) without the parents of parents?* One way is with a filtering iterator like below:

```
class FirstParentIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $iterator) {
        parent::__construct(
            new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new ParentIterator($iterator),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
            )
        );
    }
    public function accept() {
        // Only accept immediate parents of leaf elements
        return $this->hasChildren() && ! $this->getChildren()->hasChildren();
    }
}
```

---

Putting such a filter to some use makes your original loop much tidier:

```
$iterator = new FirstParentIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($comments_array));
foreach ($iterator as $row) {
    echo $row['User_ID'] . "<br>";
}
```